# Toshiba external HDD shows no media in disk management

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, external-hard-drive, toshiba-hard-drive

I have a Toshiba 2TB external HDD which was not showing in explorer (windows 7). I opened disk management, it showed the volume size and all.

First I tried assigning a letter but nothing new happened. So I formatted the disk, it took long time (even with quick format enabled). so I canceled the format.

Now it says "no media" and only one driver is installed-" Toshiba external 3.0 USB device."
I even downloaded "Easeus partition manager",it also doesn't recognize the drive.

What do I do now?